# Mutliple values for IN clause with CASE in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run this query where IN clause uses CASE to choose values between two cases.

The issue is with the hard coded value('aaa','bbb'). I cannot add multiple values inside THEN so it act as regular IN values. The hard code values will be dynamic as I will pass a variable for it.

```
select kdo.field0
from tb1 data1 inner join tb2 kdo
on kdo.field1 = 'xxx'
   and kdo.field2::DATE >='2017-08-01'::DATE
   and kdo.field0
       in (case when 'asd'!='' then 'aaa','bbb'
           else tb2.field0 end);
```

Also, I used a sub-query select inside THEN to get specific hard code values but it is also of no avail. Using single hard-coded value obviously works as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `CASE` outside `IN`:

```
select kdo.field0
from tb1 data1 inner join tb2 kdo
on kdo.field1 = 'xxx'
   and kdo.field2::DATE >='2017-08-01'::DATE
   and case when 'asd'!='' then kdo.field0 in ('aaa','bbb')
       else kdo.field0=tb2.field0 end;
```

however I'm not sure what do you mean by `'asd'!=''` since `'asd'` is a string and this will always return `true`

also, `else tb2.field0 end);` part in your statement is not an array option, it's a column name so I assume this just translates to `kdo.field0=tb2.field0` because if the previous case option is false you want to check if `kdo.field0` is equal to any of values in `tb2.field0` which is basically a join condition

Comment: 'asd' was used for testing purpose. Sorry for not mentioning that. That will be replaced by a variable in the actual query.  Your use of tb2.field0 will also work, it will have the similar functionality as mentioned in original query. Thanks for the suggestion. I am appalled that I messed up such a simple query.